# Classification of knots with unknotting number 1.

Tags: knot-invariants

Is there a classification of knots with unknotting number=1?

I can think of one infinite family at least. That is, twist the unknot $n$ times then join the two ends together.

In fact, I think maybe one could twist the unknot into a string and join the ends together to make a circle. And then form any knot with this circle and it will have unknotting number=1.

So it seems like the classification of knots with unknotting number 1 is paradoxically just as difficulat as the classification of all knots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first family are called *twist knots*, and your second family, twist knots with a knot tied into them, are called *Whitehead doubles*.  Every Whitehead double is a genus 1 unknotting number 1 knot, and Scharlemann and Thompson showed the converse that genus 1 unknotting number 1 knots are Whitehead doubles:

*Scharlemann, Martin; Thompson, Abigail*, [**Link genus and the Conway moves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02564693), Comment. Math. Helv. 64, No. 4, 527-535 (1989). [ZBL0693.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0693.57004).

While classifying unknotting number 1 knots might be difficult, maybe some good news is that unknotting number 1 knots are prime:

*Scharlemann, Martin G.*, [**Unknotting number one knots are prime**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01394778), Invent. Math. 82, 37-55 (1985). [ZBL0576.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0576.57004).

(Some context of this result is that there is the long-standing question of whether $$u(K_1\mathbin{\#}K_2)=u(K_1)+u(K_2).$$  So, if $u(K_i)\geq 1$ for each $i$, we at least have $u(K_1\mathbin{\#}K_2)\geq 2$.)

In general, every unknotting number 1 knot can be put in the following form.  Take an unknot, glue one end of a long strip to it, tie it up in some way, then take a small part of the other end and have the unknot pass through the strip transversely; this is called a *clasp band*.  Here are a few examples:

[image: Knots with clasp band presentations]

A related invariant is the *clasp number*, which is the number of such bands it takes to present a knot where the strips do not pass through the interior of the unknot, so clasp number is an upper bound for unknotting number.  For example, $3_1$ and $4_1$ have clasp number 1, but $6_2$ and $6_3$ have clasp number 2.  A clasp number 1 knot is the same thing as a Whitehead double.

(Something I wish I knew is whether there is a nice set of moves on these clasp bands that go between any two such presentations, especially a set that does not increase the number of clasp bands.)